# What causing this exception java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.view.View]

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I'm having a problem with my `firebase` project.
I followed the steps on `firebase` GitHub documentation, but I got this exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init>
[class android.view.View]
```

this is a `ViewHolder` class which is not an inner class.

```
public class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
public View mView;
public ImageView img;
public TextView title;
public TextView price;
public RatingBar stars;


ProductViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    mView = itemView;
    img = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.productImg);
    title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
    price = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtPrice);
    stars = (RatingBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
    }
}
```

and this is the firebase related code

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // Recycler adapter
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Product, ProductViewHolder> adapter =
            new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Product, ProductViewHolder>(
                    Product.class,
                    R.layout.product_list_item,
                    ProductViewHolder.class,
                    firebaseRef.child("product")) {

                @Override
                protected void populateViewHolder(ProductViewHolder productViewHolder, Product product, int i) {
                    Picasso.with(ShopsApp.getLyShopsAppContext())
                            .load(product.getImgUrl())
                            .placeholder(R.drawable.none)
                            .into(productViewHolder.img);
                    productViewHolder.title.setText(product.getTitle());
                    productViewHolder.price.setText(product.getPrice());
                    productViewHolder.stars.setRating(4.0f);
                }
            };

    recyclerView1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I'm using `firebaseRecyclerView` to populate data model,
and the `viewHolder` class is not inner class of my activity

*Note: the exception occurs when the activity that contains the `recyclerView` starts.*

Comment: Two possible causes below. If those are not it, [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36972335/edit) your question to include the minimal code with which we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Your `ProductViewHolder ` constructor is not public.

Comment: The problem solved Thans a lot

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Most likely your custom `ViewHolder` subclass is:

- missing a constructor `public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {... }` OR
- the class is defined inside another class, in which case you need to mark it as static `public static class MyViewHolder`.

Comment: Hi @Frank van Puffelen, Could you explain why the class need to be static? Thank in advance!

Comment: That's only needed when the POJO is an inner class in another class. In that case Java adds a hidden field to the class and parameter to the default constructor that allows the object to find its container. This parameter makes it that Firebase can't find the default constructor anymore. Marking the class as `static` removes the field and parameter and thus Firebase can find the parameterless constructor again.

Comment: Great :) Thanks @Frank van Puffelen!